# Computing the (in)finite-time observability Gramian.

Tags: control-theory

I'm having trouble with the observability gramian. Here's the question:

Given a system $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t), \quad y(t)=Cx(t)$ with 
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
and $C= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

a) Determine the unobservable space by means of the finite-time observability gramian $W_{O}(T)$ with $T>0$.

b) Determine the unobservable space by means of the infite-time observability Gramian $W = lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} W_{O}(T)$

What I Think:

a) Can be computed using $W_{O}(T)$ = $$\sum_{t=0}^{T-1} (A^{'})^{t}C^{'}CA^{t} $$ in which $A'$ and $C'$ denote the transpose of $A$ and $C$.

I don't know at what $t$ I should stop the summation and I don't know if $A^0$ = identity or not?

b) can be computed using $A^{'}W+WA=-C^{'}C$ solving this gives $W$=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
the unobservable space then equals im($W$) which is 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Thank in advance for the help.

Kind regards,

Comment: The system you give is continuous, however the finite-time Gramian you calculate seems to be for a discrete system.

Comment: you're right.The gramian should be computed with a different formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the system you give, the observability grammian is $\begin{bmatrix} C\\ CA\end{bmatrix}$ or 
$$
W_o = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$W_o$ is rank 1 < 2, so the system fails to be observable. The unobservable subspace is exactly the kernel (null space) of $W_o$, which must be of dimension $2-1 =1$. Since $[1,-1]^{tr}$ is an element in the null space of $W_o$ then $\ker W_o = \text{span}\{[1,-1]^{tr} \}$, which is exactly the unobservable subspace of the system.

Note that you never need to actually calculate $\int e^{A^*t}C^*Ce^{At}dt$ for a finite dimensional system! This is always the same as $\begin{bmatrix} C\\ CA\\\ CA^2 \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n-1}\\ \end{bmatrix}$ for a state space of dimension $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Kwin.

I, indeed had the wrong formula.

The formula to calculate the continuos time finite time observability gramian is 
$W_{O}(T)=$$\int_{0}^{T} e^{A^{'}\tau}C'Ce^{A\tau} d\tau$

But I don't know at what upper bound T the interrgration should stop.

Comment: Any nonzero and finite $T$ should suffice.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen actually computing the integral form is exactly the *wrong* way to find a finite dimensional Grammian!